# Mini Database- Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.LecturerName
FROM Lecturer L
WHERE 5 > = 
(   SELECT  E.StudentID
    FROM    Class C, Enrolled E
    WHERE   C.ClassName = E.ClassName
    AND     C.LecturerID = L.LecturerID)
```

Error Message as below:-

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Anything wrong?

Comment: As the error message tells you, your subquery returns more than one row. JOIN between class and enrolled table must be filter more.

Comment: Spell out your task.

Comment: d. Retrieve the names of lecturer such that the combined enrollment of the courses that they teach is less than 5 students.

Comment: @YapChunEe: Please add your DBMS

Comment: Yes, eg S0001, S0002, S0003  for student
For lecturer LEC1001, LEC1002 ....

Comment: @JoeTaras What do you mean add your DBMS?

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: You have tagged as sql your question, but a query can be different by DBMS (Sql Server, Oracle, My Sql and so on)

Comment: Yes, your lestest Comment is working.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i am newbie at here, nice to meet you 
:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `COUNT(*)` in the subquery.  Also, *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.LecturerName
FROM Lecturer L
WHERE 5 >= (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Class C JOIN
                 Enrolled E
                 ON C.ClassName = E.ClassName
            WHERE C.LecturerID = L.LecturerID
           );
```

I am guessing that the `DISTINCT` is not needed in the `SELECT`.

You don't specify the database that you are using.  More typically, you would put this information in the `FROM` or `SELECT` clauses so you could see the number of students:

```
SELECT L.LecturerName, COUNT(*) as NumStudents
FROM Lecturer L JOIN
     Class C
     ON C.LecturerID = L.LecturerID JOIN
     Enrolled E
     ON C.ClassName = E.ClassName
GROUP BY L.LecturerName
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5;
```

Comment: Dear but if I've two classes (with the same Lecturer) with 4 enrolled for class you don't retrieve the lecturer. Right?

Comment: Now i trying to check, GL and Your asnwer totally different.

Comment: Different from what?

Answer (score 3):

You can join in the main query `Lecturer` and `Class` and apply a distinct, so you restrict your query about `Enrollment` with less 5 students (with a subquery)

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.LecturerName
FROM Lecturer L
JOIN Class C
    ON L.LecturerID = C.LecturerID
WHERE
    (SELECT count(E.ClassName)
     FROM Enrollment E
     WHERE C.ClassName = E.ClassName
     AND C.LecturerID = L.LecturerID) < 5
```

Comment: d. Retrieve the names of lecturer such that the combined enrollment of the courses that they teach is less than 5 students.

Comment: Ok! Have a nice day. Because you're newbie, you can accept answer (click on tick under down arrow) if accomplishes your aim